# Different color scheme for monitor and printer with gedit

Tags: ubuntu, printer, colors, gedit

When I use `gedit` (the Ubuntu default text editor), I like to use a dark color scheme like *Oblivion*.

A problem I'm facing however is that when the documented is printed the result is not very accessible: the colors are rather light. The white text is inverted to black, but the more dark green colors are converted to light green. Keyword written in bold white (like `if` in Java) are not even printed at all.

I wonder whether it is possible to define two color schemes: one to use on a monitor and one to use when printing the source code.